# Compiling vim 8.0 with Python 3 support resulting in SIGABRT

Tags: python, python-3.x, vim, compilation

I'm having real trouble getting Python 3 working inside vim. I've downloaded the latest 8.0 source from the vim github, and I've been configuring it with this, using the Anaconda distribution including Python 3.6:

```
./configure \
    --with-features=huge \
    --enable-multibyte \
    --enable-cscope \
    --enable-multibyte \
    --enable-python3interp=yes   \
    --with-features=huge \
    --with-python3-config-dir=$ANACONDA_PATH/lib/python3.6/config-3.6m-x86_64-linux-gnu \
    --enable-fail-if-missing \
    --prefix=$LOCAL_BIN
```

Make the usual way (`make -j`), install, then run, test `Python 3` inclusion with:

```
:python3 import sys
```

And then I get a `SIGABRT` killing vim. I added the Vundle `klen/python-mode`, which kills vim on startup with:

```
Fatal Python error: PyThreadState_Get: no current thread
```

I've seen a bunch of people have had this error using YCM on OS X with MacPorts / system bundled versions of Python getting confused. That doesn't seem to be the case here, I'm running a Debian machine running 3.16 kernel, checking `vim --version` shows that python3 is correctly compiled in, and it points to the correct areas for the python3.6 library (no conflict in `/usr/local/lib`):

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Aug 19 2017 11:46:55)
Included patches: 1-966
Compiled by Matt
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl             +file_in_path    +mouse_sgr       +tag_old_static
+arabic          +find_in_path    -mouse_sysmouse  -tag_any_white
+autocmd         +float           +mouse_urxvt     -tcl
-balloon_eval    +folding         +mouse_xterm     +termguicolors
-browse          -footer          +multi_byte      -terminal
++builtin_terms  +fork()          +multi_lang      +terminfo
+byte_offset     +gettext         -mzscheme        +termresponse
+channel         -hangul_input    +netbeans_intg   +textobjects
+cindent         +iconv           +num64           +timers
+clientserver    +insert_expand   +packages        +title
+clipboard       +job             +path_extra      -toolbar
+cmdline_compl   +jumplist        -perl            +user_commands
+cmdline_hist    +keymap          +persistent_undo +vertsplit
+cmdline_info    +lambda          +postscript      +virtualedit
+comments        +langmap         +printer         +visual
+conceal         +libcall         +profile         +visualextra
+cryptv          +linebreak       -python          +viminfo
+cscope          +lispindent      +python3         +vreplace
+cursorbind      +listcmds        +quickfix        +wildignore
+cursorshape     +localmap        +reltime         +wildmenu
+dialog_con      -lua             +rightleft       +windows
+diff            +menu            -ruby            +writebackup
+digraphs        +mksession       +scrollbind      +X11
-dnd             +modify_fname    +signs           +xfontset
-ebcdic          +mouse           +smartindent     -xim
+emacs_tags      -mouseshape      +startuptime     -xpm
+eval            +mouse_dec       +statusline      +xsmp_interact
+ex_extra        -mouse_gpm       -sun_workshop    +xterm_clipboard
+extra_search    -mouse_jsbterm   +syntax          -xterm_save
+farsi           +mouse_netterm   +tag_binary
system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
    user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
    user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
    defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
fall-back for $VIM: "/home/matt/.local/share/vim"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H     -g -O2 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1
Linking: gcc   -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,--as-needed -o vim    -lSM -lICE -lXt -lX11 -lXdmcp -lSM -lICE  -lm -ltinfo -lnsl   -ldl     -L/home/matt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/config-3.6m-x86_64-linux-gnu -lpython3.6m -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lrt -lm
```

I also ran this compiled instance through `gdb`, and `info shared` shows that the correct `libpython3.6` is loaded from my anaconda directory. I'm really lost by this. Can anyone think of something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

So I was dealing with same problem today, and I managed to fix it by configuring the VIM compilation with

```
--enable-python3interp=dynamic
```

I found the advice at https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/issues/2855. On my site, I didn't even need to meddle with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or similar.