# Vim could not load libpython3.7m.a with python3 from Anaconda

Tags: python-3.x, vim, anaconda, miniconda

I'm trying to use Anaconda python3.7 + vim 8.1 + jedi-vim on Rocks 7.0 (Manzanita) but I get an error saying that `libpython3.7m.a` cannot be loaded and I can't find a solution.

First things first. I have to compile vim by myself because the vim installed by default has only `+python` and I have to use python3. 
I cloned the git and, following several other suggestions found online I configure vim with

```
./configure --enable-cscope --enable-multibyte --enable-python3interp=dynamic --with-features=huge --with-python-config-dir=/home/mazzi/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/config-3.7m-x86_64-linux-gnu --with-tlib=ncurses --enable-fail-if-missing --prefix=/home/mazzi/.local
```

The `prefix` is due to the fact that I don't have root access and its output of can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/rYh6hKSK). Please note that during the whole procedure I had to stay inside a conda environment, otherwise the configuration would fail saying that no python3 was found.
I then `make`, with this [output](https://pastebin.com/FWyDLDqe), and `make install` with this other [output](https://pastebin.com/yD1dxWs4).
I check vim [version](https://pastebin.com/KmBwKfa3) and everything seems ok.
Finally, I start vim normally (`/home/mazzi/.local/bin` is on the PATH, before the system paths, and the `vim` command points to `~/.local/bin/vim`) and type `:py3 pass` but I get the following error:

```
E370: Could not load library libpython3.7m.a
E263: Sorry, this command is disabled, the Python library could not be loaded.
```

What can I do?

**Additional info**
Some of my sources:

- https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/wiki/Building-Vim-from-source (without sudo and just to be clear I did not try YouCompleteMe due to some issues in the past that forced me to go to jedi-vim)
- https://gist.github.com/hxhc/778d7c3a3ad491dedf3675a47275a979
- [Compiling vim 8.0 with Python 3 support resulting in SIGABRT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45775384/compiling-vim-8-0-with-python-3-support-resulting-in-sigabrt)
- https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/issues/2855#issuecomment-352181535